# XSLT with namespace causing an issue

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, transformation

I want to grab "LIVE" out of the XML below. I've read similar posts and have been using the local-name() function as a result, but no matter what XSLT I use I can't get it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cns:customer xmlns:cns="https://services.cns.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://services.cns.com docs/xsd/customer.xsd">
    <cns:userId>1001</cns:userId>
    <cns:status>LIVE</cns:status>
    <cns:type wholesale="true" suspended="false">W1</cns:type>
    <cns:properties>
        <cns:property>
            <cns:name>Name</cns:name>
            <cns:value>Bob</cns:value>
        </cns:property>
    </cns:properties>
</cns:customer>
```

Here is the XSLT I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='status']/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am testing using Oxygen application. I think the processor is Saxon 6.5.5.

The output I get is:

```
1001
LIVE
W1

    Name
    Bob
```

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Answer based on your  your recent edit to the question.

just use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='status']/text()">
        value: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The 1001, W1 ....etc are not matched by any template and are therefore handled by the default template ,which just echoes it into the output.

Now you also make the namespace version work:

```
<xsl:template match="/c:customer/c:status" xmlns:c="https://services.cns.com">
    value: <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks again. The second XSLT snippet in your reply returns "value:". The first returns "value: LIVE", so I see what you mean about the default template. I don't want any output from that default template - I just want what I asked for - is there anyway to just get the output "LIVE" and nothing else?

Comment: use ` <xsl:template match="*" xmlns:c="https://services.cns.com">
        <xsl:value-of select="/c:customer/c:status/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: please mark as answer if you feel this was the answer to your question, tx :)

Answer (score 1):

You should register your namespaces with your XSLT processor. But if you somehow cannot, you should be able to execute the following XPath expression:

```
//*[local-name()="status"]/text()
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I've done, so it must be something else that's wrong? `<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='status']/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Adding this to the XSLT seems to give me exactly what I need    `<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='status']"/>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: but only with some XSLT processors!! Aaarghhh!